# MYSQL : INSERT с проверкой условия из другой таблицы

Tags: mysql, join, update, insert

имеется таблица, в которой хранятся пользователи `members (id, name)`, 
и есть вторая таблица, в которой нужно обновить несколько строк `price (id, userid, name, value)`. таблицы связаны между собой `members.id=price.userid`.

чтобы исключить возможность пользователю менять чужой прайс, хочу 
обновлять строку, только если `id` этой строки связано с залогиненым пользователем.

для одной строки всё понятно:

```
UPDATE price 
   JOIN members AS members.id=price.userid
   SET name='some', value='0.01'
   WHERE members.id='logged_user' AND price.id='1';
```

но нужно менять сразу несколько десятков строк, и в каждой может быть подлог (пользователь подменит post-запрос и влезет в чужой прайс). делать десятки отдельных запросов для каждой строки не хочется из спортивного интереса минимизации обращений к БД. для многострочного UPDATE я обычно пользуюсь конструкцией:

```
INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

но не могу придумать, куда тут запихнуть проверку поля из другой таблицы. JOIN'a у INSERT ведь нет.

Comment: А зачем вам здесь `JOIN`? Раз в `update`'е вы делаете `members.id='logged_user'`, значит `members.id` вы уже знаете и можно сразу, без `join`'а, указать его: `WHERE price.userid='logged_user'`

Comment: на самом деле, я тут немного упростил чтоб не расползаться мыслью по древу. и не подумал, что при таком упрощении смысл JOIN теряется. на самом деле price спрятан в третьем уровне, так что без JOIN'a никак: `members (id,name)`, `menu (id,userid,link,title)`, `price (id,menuid,name,value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вопрос снимается. решил так: чтоб не делать сотни запросов с UPDATE .. JOIN для каждой строки отдельно, запроса всего два:

1. выбирает все возможные ID строчек прайса для данного пользователя

   ```
   $query = "SELECT price.* FROM price 
      JOIN menu ON price.menuid=menu.id
      WHERE menu.userid='USERID' AND menu.id='ID'";
   ```
2. проверяю значения ID, полученные из формы. если совпадают с теми, что получил из первого запроса - добавляем в массив `$set[] = "("  . $id . "," . $value . ")"`.
3. формируем запрос на UPDATE:

   ```
   $query = "INSERT INTO price (id, value) 
      VALUES ".implode(",", $set)." 
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=VALUES('value')";
   ```